# Override a controller in Adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, controllers

Currently I'm trying to override the GroupController of Mage_Adminhtml_Customer so I can add some code for saving my custom field in the Customer Groups menu. As you can think it doesn't really work as I want what means that it seems that my controller is ignored by Magento so far but I don't get the mistake I've made. Here are the snippets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    [...]
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable</Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

And the controller:

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/Customer/controllers/GroupController.php';

class Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable_GroupController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_GroupController
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        die(':D'); //just for testing
    }
}
```

Can anybody see what's missing? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are requiring the wrong file. This `Mage/Adminhtml/Customer/controllers/GroupController.php` should be `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php`

Comment: Oh, yep, you're right. Thank you! However Magento is still not amazed and ignores it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put your controller file under an Admintml folder. Better to use a similar folder path of the class which you are going to override.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    [...]
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable_Adminhtml</Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Controller file :

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php';

class Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable_Adminhtml_GroupController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_GroupController
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        die(':D'); //just for testing
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, the missing Adminhtml folder was causing the trouble. Thanks!

Comment: And also so (IMPORTANT for this method) that the path to the controller under the Adminhtml sould match the path of the overloaded controller.
for instance:
Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/productController.php
My_Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/productController.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok start testing.

First add a die before the class definition to check whether the class file is loaded.

Then add a space in `<conf ig>` to check whether your config file is loaded.

Check the backend `System > Config > Advanced` whether you can prevent the output of your module (if yes, the `module.xml` in `app/etc/modules` is at least loaded)

What url do you test?
should be:

http://magento.local//group/save

Disable the auth key in the backend (don'T ask me where) to prevent an error with the missing auth key in the url

And the last words: Code looks good, I think the mistake is somewhere else.