# Custom Order Status getUrl?

Tags: adminhtml, order-status

Right now i am using Magento 1.9.1.

I am working around on the code so i can add new Status in the mass Actions select menu http://mymagento.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/944964552ee91bc0eeeb09f63a57c97e/ page.

Right now when we select some orders we have this "Actions" select menu to change the status of all selected orders.

Here you can see for which "Actions" select menu i am talking about:

[image]

I created new Order status.

When i opened:
/public_html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

I see the following code:

```
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
    ));
```

These lines adds actions in this "Actions" select menu.

So in that manner i added my custom created Order status like this:

```
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('receive_in_our_office', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Receive in our Office'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl(''),
    ));
```

The problem is that when i select 'Receive in our Office' and press Submit just nothing happens. I am sure that this problem comes from my blank `'url'  => $this->getUrl(''),`

So guys how i can properly set my `'url'  => $this->getUrl(''),` to the correct URL for my custom order status with code `"receive_in_our_office"` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you would need to make your own module with Adminhtml controller.
The controller would have an action like `statusAction`

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';

class [Namespace]_[Module]_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
    {
       public function statusAction()
        {
            $orders = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
            foreach ($orders as $orderId)
            {
                $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                $_order->setStatus("Receive in our Office");

                try {
                    $_order->save();
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("{$e}"); 
                }
            }


            $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/');
        }
    }
```

With a `config.xml` looking something like this

```
<config>    
    [...]
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <[Namespace]_[Module] before="Mage_Adminhtml">[Namespace]_[Module]_Adminhtml</[Namespace]_[Module]>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    [...]
</config>
```

Resulting in an url like: `$this->getUrl('*/sales_order/status')`

Comment: Thank you so much!
Can you please give me more detailed info about how i can make this module ? Where and how i must create the module files and locate them? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10489/50
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282956/387136

These 2 links should give you more info

Comment: Sander can you please check this out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40222/creating-a-new-extension-for-magento-1-9 It's releated to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->getUrl('')` give only admin url with without secret key.

And then that mean you need to `add action and controllers`.

As `'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),` ,means your action controller class
`Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` function  `pdfinvoicesAction()` you need an new action..means function here.