# export fails on custom grid

Tags: admin, sales-order, export, grid

I have changed the transaction grid so I needed to do it in local folder because they were comming from Core files. here is the folders structure

[image]

so in the controller I have done this:

```
   public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $fileName = 'Transaction.csv';
    $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Transactions_Grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

and in the Grid.php :

```
    class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Transactions_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
    {
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
            $helper = Mage::helper('Adminhtml');
            //some code
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
            return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }
//some code and functions
}
```

it does not work I could not see anything in log files. I'm not sure why we have this path `*/*/exportCsv` what does it mean? well it worked in all modules so I just did it but i don't understand it.

also I do not know about the $helper, what should be written I tried Mage_Adminhtml but it gave me error of something like Mage_Mage_Adminhtml_... so I guessed it should be only Adminhtml

I also did this:

```
 public function exportCsvAction()
    {   
          $fileName   = 'Transaction.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_transactions_grid')
            ->getCsv();

        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);

    }
```

no result 404 not found

I logged a message in this function and I have realized that it does not even go to the exportCsvAction function for some reason

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot override controllers in `app/code/local` like other classes because they are not loaded with the Magento autoloader but included explicitly (Hint: their paths don't follow the same convention, `controllers` is not part of the class name)

So, the original controller is used and that's why the exportCsv action does not exist.

You will have to write a proper module instead of working on a copy in `app/code/local`, at least for the controller. You can add your own controller to the `adminhtml` route, as explained here: [Override a controller in Adminhtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10454/override-a-controller-in-adminhtml)

As for your question, what `*/*/exportCsv` means: this denotes a *route*, which contains of frontname, controller and action. `*` means "same as current", so it is the route for the `exportCsvAction()` action method in the current controller.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved the problem with your guidance ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You did a mistake here

```
$helper = Mage::helper('Adminhtml');
```

**You have to define adminhtml in small letter**

```
$helper = Mage::helper('adminhtml');
```

So only your getting `Mage_Mage_Adminhtml` is not a class.

```
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', $helper->__('CSV')); 
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still having problem, it redirects me to a page and not working