# Magento Approve Customer Review

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I'm using magento 1.9 version.
I'm trying to add a image field in magento customer product review page. It gets submitted and saved in DB. When trying to approve the review, the custom field was not saved again(ie., is saves as empty).
How to save the field again with same data saved while submitted.

Comment: You don't need to use setData(). You need to use set<Field>() to save specific field data.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I'm not used setData(). I want to know, which action is called when admin approves the review and how to rewrite it.

Comment: File path is app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php

Comment: There are many posts to help on how to override admin controller in magento. Please have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10454/override-a-controller-in-adminhtml or http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Comment: Thank you @MohitKumarArora. I need to rewrite this action too. Am right.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me, in whichBlock file i've to add the field inorder to add the field review form in admin panel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44097/discussion-between-magentomad-and-mohit-kumar-arora).